# Writing and showing Hebrew letters on pdf

Tags: java, pdf, hebrew

I am writing contents on pdf file.

When i write Hebrew letters ("שלום") The letters dont appear on the pdf.

Waybe its a Encode issue, anyhow how can i write Hebrew on a pdf file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306244/java-pdfbox-text-encoding

This seems to be in a similar vein to your question.

Comment: https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples/blob/develop/samples/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/fonts/ArabicExample.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be an encoding issue, but it is difficult to tell without knowing how you are writing to the PDF file (what library, what encoding etc...).

Another thing to look at are the embedded fonts used in the PDF - by default there wouldn't be any and you would need to embed a Hebrew font to be used for Hebrew text. You would need to ensure that you have the rights to embed and distribute such a font before doing so.

Comment: i am using IText for writing, and for Encode "UTF-8". about your remarks, how can i embed Hebrew font? i am suppose to do it with my Java or in my pdf reader software? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelA - You will need to use your PDF library and embed the font using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need the font with Hebrew letters (glyphs) embedded in PDF.