# How to create a PDF document from languages of Unicode char set regarding using third party Fonts

Tags: java, fonts, itext, pdfbox

I'm using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) and [iText](http://itextpdf.com) to create a simple (just paragraphs) pdf document from various languages. Something like :

**pdfBox**:

```
private static void createPdfBoxDocument(File from, File to) {
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        document = new TextToPDF().createPDFFromText(new FileReader(from));
        document.save(new FileOutputStream(to));
    } finally {
        if (document != null)
            document.close();
    }
}

private void createPdfBoxDoc() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, COSVisitorException {
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    PDType1Font font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 400);
    contentStream.drawString("š");
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();
    document.save("test.pdf");
    document.close();
}
```

**itext**:

```
private static Font blackFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

private static void createITextDocument(File from, File to) {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(to));
    document.open();
    addContent(document, getParagraphs(from));
    document.close();
}

private static void addContent(Document document, List<String> paragraphs) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.size(); i++) {
        document.add(new Paragraph(paragraphs.get(i), blackFont));
    }
}
```

The input files are encoded in UTF-8 and some languages of Unicode char set, like Russian alphabet etc., are not rendered properly in pdf. The Fonts in both libraries don't support Unicode charset I suppose and I can't find any documentation on how to add and use third party fonts. Could please anybody help me out with an example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using iText, it has quite good support.

In iText in Action (chapter 2.2.2) you can read more.

You have to download some unicode Fonts like **arialuni.ttf** and do it like this :

```
    public static File fontFile = new File("fonts/arialuni.ttf");

    public static void createITextDocument(File from, File to) throws DocumentException, IOException {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(to));
        document.open();
        writer.getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(true);
        BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        FontSelector fs = new FontSelector();
        fs.addFont(new Font(unicode));

        addContent(document, getParagraphs(from), fs);
        document.close();
    }

    private static void addContent(Document document, List<String> paragraphs, FontSelector fs) throws DocumentException { 

        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.size(); i++) {
            Phrase phrase = fs.process(paragraphs.get(i));
            document.add(new Paragraph(phrase));
        }
    }
```

arialuni.ttf  fonts work for me, so far I checked it support for

```
BG, ES, CS, DA, DE, ET, EL, EN, FR, IT, LV, LT, HU, MT, NL, PL, PT, RO, SK, SL, FI, SV
```

and only PDF in Romanian language wasn't created properly...

With **PDFBox** it's almost the same:

```
private void createPdfBoxDoc() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, COSVisitorException {
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, "fonts/arialuni.ttf");
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 400);
    contentStream.drawString("š");
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();
    document.save("test.pdf");
    document.close();
}
```

However as Gagravarr says, it doesn't work because of this issue [PDFBOX-903](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-903) . Even with 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT version. Maybe trunk will work. I suggest you to use iText. It works there perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425251/using-pdfbox-to-write-utf-8-encoded-strings-to-a-pdf) helpful - it confirms that you can't do what you need with one of the standard type 1 fonts, as they're Latin1 only

In theory, you just need to [embed a suitable font](http://www.pdfbox.org/userguide/fonts.html#Embedding+TrueType+Fonts) into the document, which handles all your codepoints, and use that. However, there's at least [one open bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-903) with writing unicode strings, so there's a chance it might not work just yet... Try the latest pdfbox from svn trunk too though to see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I just copied the font that supported UTF8 (or whatever language you want)  to a directory (or you can used Windows fonts path) and add some code, it looked like this

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("c:\\a.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,true);
Font font = new Font(baseFont);
document.add(new Paragraph("Not English Text",font));
```

Now, you can use this font to show your text in various languages.

Answer (score 0):

//use this code.Sometimes setfont() willnot work with Paragraph

```
try
{

    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(name);

    Document doc=new Document();

    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);

    doc.open();

    Font f=new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,50.0f,Font.UNDERLINE,BaseColor.RED);
    Paragraph p=new Paragraph("New PdF",f);

    p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);

    doc.add(p);
    doc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```