# How to set the encoding of a font used in iText?

Tags: java, encoding, itext

How to set encoding in iText. When I write in another language it writes empty spaces. Any idea? 
I found it :) but now I dont know how to make this font for data in table do u know ?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181518/how-to-create-a-pdf-document-from-languages-of-unicode-char-set-regarding-using

Answer (score 0):

So you're creating a table with cells and you want the text in the cells to have a font that is different from Helvetica.

That's easy: you already know how to create a `Font` and a `Paragraph` (or a `Phrase`) from the answer in the comment.

Now create a `PdfPCell` using a `Phrase` in the constructor (*text mode*) or by adding a `Paragraph` with `addElement()` (*composite mode*).

Now when you use `addCell()`, pass that `PdfPCell` instance instead of a `String`.

Also: read the documentation before you start coding: http://itextpdf.com/book