# How to write unicode text to pdf with pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I try to use `Apache PDFBox 1.8.6` to create a PDF in `Java`. (See code below)

If I write the string: `Hello! 123 abc äöüß` everything works fine.
But if I add an € sign or it's equivalent \u20ac the String gets messed up:
`þÿ H e l l o ! 1 2 3 a b c ä ö ü ß ¬ ¬ ¦`
I think this has something to do with the encoding, since programms like OpenOffice can export pdf with € or other Unicode signs without a problem.

So what do I have to do to write Unicode String to PDF?

```
try {
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER;
        //font.setFontEncoding(new EncodingManager().getEncoding(COSName.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING));
        stream.setFont(font, 14);
        stream.beginText();
        stream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
        stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(20, 750);
        String text = "Hello! 123 abc äöüß € \u20ac";
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
        stream.drawString(text);
        stream.endText();
        stream.stroke();
        stream.close();
        doc.save("test.pdf");
        doc.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is with Pdf font with COURIER, look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425251/using-pdfbox-to-write-utf-8-encoded-strings-to-a-pdf

Comment: Maybe you should use `TextToPdf` see `TestUnicodeTest.java` on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-903

Comment: possible duplicate of [PdfBox encode symbol currency euro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260344/pdfbox-encode-symbol-currency-euro)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425251/using-pdfbox-to-write-utf-8-encoded-strings-to-a-pdf Duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, PDFBox did not support Unicode fonts. That is, until now: after [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2634) has been fixed by a great guy, the trunk of PDFBox 2.0.0 shows my Unicode perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, this helps a lot