# Create a bullet list item using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0 to do a HTML to PDF conversion. This is going quite well, except that I am stuck at converting the list item tag to a bullet (black, round, disc).

The official Unicode bullet character is U+2022, however none of the fonts in PDFBox support characters above the 8-bit range. I have tried embedding and using some of the fonts in the Windows font folder "C:\Windows\Fonts", but they do not seem to support more than 8-bit either.

PDFBox has a class called PDListAttributeObject which seems to have something to do with lists and bullets, but I cannot find any examples of how to use it.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I use PDListAttributeObject in PDFBox to write a bullet character to the contentstream? and if so, how?
2. Are there any standard Windows fonts that can render a bullet character?
3. Any other suggestions on how to get a bullet character written to a PDF?

Comment: Doesn't work with 1.8, you'll need 2.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525213/how-to-write-unicode-text-to-pdf-with-pdfbox

Comment: I am using 2.0. Sorry, forgot to mention that..

Comment: Then please edit your question to mention that you're using 2.0. Have you looked at the EmbeddedFonts.java example? https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/EmbeddedFonts.java?view=markup&sortby=date

Comment: I have now tried the EmbeddedFonts.java example. I can get the bullet character using that specific font. This will serve my purpose fine :-)

Comment: Just to clarify, can I then only use the LiberationSans-Regular.ttf font to render a bullet?.

Comment: Glad it works. If you like, answer your question yourself, so that it will help others :-)

Comment: You can use any font that has the symbol.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there any way to see if a Windows font has that symbol? Other than trial and error?

Comment: PDType0Font.hasGlyph()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, in this case, was to use the font included with PDFBox 2.0 (LiberationSans-Regular.ttf).

As a follow-up, I will now try to check which standard Windows fonts can render the bullet character. Perhaps by iterating over the fonts in the Windows/Fonts folder and checking using the PDType0Font.hasGlyph() method.

Thanks [Tilman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) :-)