# how to print unusual characters on PDF (using pdfbox)

Tags: java, encode, pdfbox

I am trying to create a new pdf from scratch, but I cant seem to print special characters correctly, for example I try to print the following string in the PDF:

```
『I like 《this string》 yeah.』
```

and get

```
þÿ0I like 0this string0 yeah.0
```

The result is correctly printed by means of the logger and println, would anyone know how to do it, allready tried ascii encoding like \u008A.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PDFBox to write UTF-8 encoded strings to a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425251/using-pdfbox-to-write-utf-8-encoded-strings-to-a-pdf)

Comment: allready tried that, no result, kinda better, but still does not work

Comment: UTF-8 is not supported in the official release 1.8.8. But it is supported (since a few days ago!) in the unreleased 2.0 version, which you can get with svn. https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#scm

Comment: Furthermore, please make sure the font you use contains a glyph for that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now possible to print utf-8 characters with PDFBOX. You need to download (https://github.com/apache/pdfbox) the latest trunk version and compile it (you can compile it using maven it is the best option belive me). The second thing that you need is a ttf font that has the glphys you are using in it.

The code that works for me:

```
package utftext;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font;

public class utftext {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);
        PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("E:\\arialuni.ttf"));
        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        String text = "ssdfg #$%&&English 012 čćžšđ ČĆŽŠĐ as äöüÖÜÄ";
        stream.beginText();
        stream.setFont(font, 12);
        stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(50, 600);
        stream.drawString(text);
        stream.endText();
        stream.close();
        document.save("type0.pdf");
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any source for arialuni.ttf (or any other reasonable unicode font) that has MIT, Apache, BSD, or similar license?